# Resolve web Locator in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Can we write a class in our Selenium framework to identify witch locator is passed by the user? 
It means.

```
public class ResolveLocator {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static String uiUsernameTXT =   "//input[@id='username']";

    public static WebElement ResolveLocatorL(String uiElement) {


        String checkLType = uiElement.toString();
        WebElement returnLType = null;

        switch (checkLType.charAt(0)) {
        case '/':  returnLType = driver.findElement(By.xpath(uiElement)); break;
        case 'c':  returnLType = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(uiElement)); break;
        case 'i':  returnLType =driver.findElement(By.id(uiElement));; break;
        case 'l':  returnLType = driver.findElement(By.linkText(uiElement)); break;
        }

        return returnLType; 
    }
 }
```

If user passes a XPath as a locator this class have to identify and return a correct code block of selenium.

Comment: xpath does not always start from /

Comment: why you need this ?? can I ask?

Comment: I plan to maintain different class as a Object map.

Comment: Why are you passing around `String` instead of `By`? Why are your users passing in locators??? Who are your users?

Answer (score 0):

rather than charAt(0), we can use naming convention to find it easily

```
uiUsernameTXT_xpath= //so and so
```

as we are writing as strings. split the string with "_" and go for last one and return location type. else good to use By operator

```
static By uiUsernameTX=By.xpath(".//* so and so");
```